# mysql : using like return duplicate row count

Tags: php, mysql, postal-code

i have an issue on the below

table1

first case :

```
postcode
LS1 1LS
```

second case:

```
postcode
LS11LS
```

table2

```
    postcode| region
    LS1 | Leeds
    LS11    | Leeds
```

and i am using the below query to count the region versus related postcode

```
SELECT table2.region as 'Region', COUNT( table2.postcode ) as  'count'
FROM table1
INNER JOIN table2 ON table1.postcode LIKE CONCAT( table2.postcode,  '%' ) 
WHERE table1.postcode >  ''
GROUP BY Region
```

on applying that on table 1 first case i get

```
Leeds | 1
```

on applying it on table 1 second case i get

```
Leeds | 2
```

for some reason on this postcode / similar postcodes where the other half is exactly like the first part and there is no spaces in between the like inner join returns the count as 2.

any solution for this ?

see this [sqlfiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/58d39/1)

Comment: I guess I am not following you data example.  How would the Leeds entry of `LS2` be joined to either of `LS1 1LS` or `LS11LS`?  Do both `LS1 1LS` and `LS11LS` exist in table 1 at the same time?

Comment: I'm just as confused -- "LS1" is never LIKE "LS2%"...

Comment: @MikeBrant sorry its LS1 , edited , and yes entries  may occur on one table by either LS1 1LS or LS11LS by an end user mistake

Comment: @AhmedElGamil [Cannot repeat](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/38121/1). Are you sure you weren't testing case 2 by inserting the second row while keeping the first, which would give 2 matching rows?

Comment: hmm this fiddle is pretty fine, my code is exactly the same as here and it only gives count 2 if i changed this record to LS11LS with no space , i truncated the table and still same .. ill recheck my code

Comment: @JoachimIsaksson i think i got it , i have 2 records on the table2  referring to the LEEDS region , i have LS1 | LEEDS and another one LS11 | LEEDS  so its pretty logical why i have 2 , but any solution for this ?

Answer (score 0):

If you have two entries in table one with values `LS1 1LS` and `LS11LS`, your join will match both of these, giving you a count of 2.